# Flatlist scroll references with getItemLayoutProp

Tags: reactjs, listview, react-native, scroll

I've got a little problem with flatlist and scroll methods.
I have flatlist with comments and if new one is added I want to scroll list to the bottom to see added comment.

Using **scrollToIndex** doesn't work properly, native keep showing errors due to lack of getItemLayout, and here is another problem with setting this function - every item can have different size.

**scrollToEnd** has some issues, sometimes it scrolls to almost bottom of the page, sometimes to headerComponent elements which are set in flatlist props.
Do you have any ideas how to make it scroll to the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

To use scrollToIndex you need to use getItemLayout. There is no point in using it if you have no intention to use getItemLayout. Here is an example taken from the react-native docs:

```
class ScrollToExample extends Component {

  getItemLayout = (data, index) => (
    { length: 50, offset: 50 * index, index }
  )


  scrollToIndex = () => {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random(Date.now()) * 
    this.props.data.length);
    this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: 
    randomIndex});
  }

  scrollToItem = () => {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random(Date.now()) * 
    this.props.data.length);
    this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: "" + 
    randomIndex});
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <FlatList
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
      keyExtractor={item => item}
      getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
      initialScrollIndex={50}
      initialNumToRender={2}
      renderItem={({ item, index}) => (
          <View style={{...style, backgroundColor: this.getColor(index)}}>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      {...this.props}
    />
);
```

}
}

https://gist.github.com/joshyhargreaves/b8eb67d24ce58a6d8bffb469f7eeaf39

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well I'm not really sure how this can help if I'm not able to use getItemLayout in this list :/

Comment: @JakubSzczepanik Don't keep me in suspense anyway. Why can't you use it in your flatlist?

Comment: @JakubSzczepanik It still scrolls to that index regardless the size of the individual comment items. You can also pass in that data in getItemLayout. So maybe if you want to track the size of each item you can store that data in the flatlist and pass it into getItemLayout as it renders